# Line tangent to the natural log

Tags: calculus

I want to find a line that passes through $(0,-1)$ and is tangent to $\ln(x)$.

I've tried saying: ''I want to find a line that has the slope $1/x$ and passes through $(0,-1)$" but this yields:

$$y=kx+m \\ \Rightarrow 1= \frac{1}{0} +m$$

And the logic is already broken at this point.

Comment: Sorry, I meant (0,-1)

Comment: Your flaw is plugging in $x=0$ to get the slope. The derivative gives the slope of the tangent for the value of $x$ *at the point of tangency*, not just anywhere. The line isn't tangent to the curve at $x=0$--in fact, $x=0$ isn't in the domain of the function being graphed.

Answer (score 4):

The line tangent to $\ln{x}$ at $x=a$ is

$$y=\ln{a}+\frac{1}{a}(x-a)$$

You want $y=-1$ when $x=0$, so solve for a in

$$-1=\ln{a}+\frac{1}{a}(-a)$$

Comment: Why is the line given by that equation...?

Comment: If you are familiar with Taylor's theorem, then this is just the first two terms of the series. If not, then write it out in point slope form and solve for $y=f(x)$:

$$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$
$$f(x)-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)$$

Answer (score 0):

First line of your query.

Slope between $ (0,-1) , ( x, \ln x ) $ is

$ \dfrac {ln\ x +1}{x} $

which should be a maximum for tangency. So applying Quotient rule

$ \dfrac {ln\ x +1}{x}  =  \dfrac {1/x}{1}$

Solving, x =1, and  y = 0.

Find this slope and equation of line through any of the above points.